# Question regarding supports of random variables and their transformations

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

**Disclaimer**: I preface by saying, I am currently reading "Hogg, McKean, and Craig, introduction to mathematical statistics", hence, kindly forgive me if I get some definition/concept wrong here, as all of these are stitched together by me from various random sources. The book *does not* talk about any of this.

**Some preliminary definitions**: Let $X$ be a random variable $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, and let $P_X$ be a probability $P_X:\mathcal{B_0} \to [0,1]$, where $\mathcal{B_0}$ is the Borel Sigma algebra, defined on $X$. Here ($\Omega$, $\Sigma(\Omega)$,$P$) form a probability space, and ($\mathbb{R}$,$\mathcal{B_0}$,$P_X$), where $P_X$ is the induced probability, also form a probability space. Let $Y=g(x)$ be a measurable function $g:\text{Range(X)}\to \mathbb{R}$, and let $P_Y:\mathcal{B_0} \to [0,1]$ be "induced" by $P_X$. That is, $P_Y(\text{some set in }\mathcal{B_0}):=P_X(g^{-1}(\text{some set in }\mathcal{B_0}))$. The associated sigma algebra for $\text{range}(X)$ I shall take to be $\mathcal{B_0}$. I hope till here, things are properly defined (?).

Now I define my "support" $R_X$ of the random variable $X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ to be the smallest closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $P_X(R_X)=1$. Or equivalently, $R_X:=\{x\in\mathbb{R} :\forall \ \varepsilon>0, P_X(V_{\varepsilon}(x))>0 \}$. In a similar vein, for $Y$, $R_Y$ would be the smallest closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $P_Y(R_Y)=P_X(g^{-1}(R_Y))=1$, or again, equivalently, $R_Y=\{y\in\mathbb{R} :\forall \ \delta>0, P_Y(V_{\delta}(y))=P_X(g^{-1}(V_{\delta}(y)))>0 \}$.

**Note**: When the probability density function $\text{pdf}_X(x)$ exists, another equivalent definition would be $R_X:=\text{closure}(\{x\in\mathbb{R}:\text{pdf}_X(x)>0 \})$

*My question is should it be that $R_X \subseteq g^{-1}(R_Y)$?*

I was able to show this fact for the case of finite ranged Random variables, but not the general case, based on the definitions above. If I further assume that the probability density function exists (both for $X$ and $Y$), and moreover, $y=g(x)$ is one-one and continuous (hence, monotone) on the support $R_X$ of $X$, then I can quite easily show that $R_X = g^{-1}(R_Y)$. But in any other case, I wasn't able to show my claim. Kindly provide some insights on the range of applicability of the above assertion, and (if it is true at all in the general case) provide a proof (or a counter example?) for the general case.

I would also be satisfied with a proof (or a disproof, or a counter example) in the case where the probability density function exists for both $X$ and $Y$ (referred to as "absolutely continuous" in my book)

Answer (score 0):

The question can be reframed as follows.

> Let $\mu$ be a measure a probability measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ with $F=\operatorname{supp}(\mu)$, and let $g$ be a measurable function on $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}))$. Let $H=\operatorname{supp}(\mu\circ g^{-1})$, where $\nu=\mu\circ g^{-1}$ is the measure defined by $\nu(A)=\mu(g^{-1}(A))$. What is the order inclusion relation between the sets $F$ and $g^{-1}(H)$?

Notice that  $\mu(\mathbb{R}\setminus F)=0$ for open sets are countable union of open balls and each open ball contained in the complement of the support of $\mu$ has measure zero.
Similarly, if   $H=\operatorname{supp}(\nu)$, then $\nu(H)=1$ and
$$1=\nu(H)=\mu(g^{-1}(H))=\mu(g^{-1}(H)\cap F)+\mu(g^{-1}(H)\setminus F)=\mu(g^{-1}(H)\cap F)$$
Thus $g^{-1}(H)= F$ $\mu$-a.s.

---

Examples

1. Consider the a measure $\mu$ on $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ with density $\mathbb{1}_{(0,1)}$ w.r.t to Lebesgue's measure. This is the uniform distribution in (0,1). Clearly $F=\operatorname{supp}(\mu)=[0,1]$. Consider the fractional part function $g(x)=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$. It is clear that $H:=\operatorname{supp}(\mu\circ g^{-1})=[0,1]$. Observe that $g^{-1}([0,1])=\mathbb{R}$ and thus $g^{-1}(H)\supset F$; however, $f^{-1}(H)=F$ $\mu$-a.s.
2. As in example (2), consider now the function $h(x)=1-\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)$ which takes values $0$ and $1$. Notice that the measure $\mu\circ h^{-1}$ is the singular measure $\delta_1$, that is $\mu(h^{-1}(A))=\mathbb{1}_A(1)$. Of course, $H=\operatorname{supp}(\delta_1)=\{1\}$ and  $h^{-1}(H)=\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$. In this case, $h^{-1}(H)\not\supset F$; yet, $h^{-1}(H)=F$ $\mu$-a.s.